# Как вывести статьи в django?

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Добрый день у меня вопрос как в django вывести на сайт например статьи если каждая статья например в отдельной таблице в базе данных

Comment: отдельная таблица для каждой статьи? очень похоже, что вы делаете что-то «не то». [проблема молотка и микроскопа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)?

Comment: Действительно, складывается ощущение, что вы все делаете неправильно. Посмотрите вот эти разделы справки: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример "](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Затем более подробно опишите, что именно вы делаете и как. Мы вам подскажем, что и как исправить

Comment: вам наверное лучше пересмотреть структуру базы данных